# Issues when trying to debug SpringBoot app with Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I have a SpringBoot application that I've just started working on from another developer.  I would like to set breakpoints and be able to step through the code to debug.  I have done this in the past with other SprintBoot applications easily.  I could simple start a debugging session off of Main and away it would go.

When I try to do that in this application I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory
```

I am using 4.2.7 RELEASE of SpringBeans.  I drilled into that package an the ListableBeanFactory is there, but for some reason when I try to run the started app (which contains the main method entrypoint) it can't find it.

Comment: do you have that dependency listed somewhere in your pom file? assuming maven

Comment: Try using Spring Boot run/debug configuration type and make sure the dependencies have the correct scope in pom.xml. It may help switching provided scope to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Runtime Configuration there is a field 'Use classpath of module'

May be, it is set wrong ?

That is the only problem I sometimes face when debugging spring-boot from within IntelliJ.

Comment: Sorry to the long time to respond.  This was my issue Stefan.  Thank you!